# Excel: Multiplier in a IF/OR statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

First time posting, so apologies if this is in the wrong place or is some variation on a question asked before. I had a quick look round and couldn't find a similar question.

I'm doing a workload model for academic staff in my school. I need to multiply an existing column (i) that has how many hours each teaching session lasts by either 3 hours if column `c="Seminar"` or 5 hours if column `c="Lecture"`. What I've got, copied below, comes back with the following error:

> "You've entered too many arguments for this function".

```
=IF(OR(C4="Seminar"),I4*3,I4, IF(OR(C4="Lecture"),I4*5,I4))
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add example data. It is easier to help you then.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `OR` - here's a simpler way. You only need to multiply once - your multiplier will be 3 for "Seminar", 5 for "Lecture" and 1 for anything else.

`=IF(C4="Seminar",3,IF(C4="Lecture",5,1))*I4`

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(A3="SEMINAR",B3*3,IF(A3="LECTURE",B3*5,"Not Lecture Or Seminar"))
```

[image]